# c# Write a line into a text file at specific line number

Tags: c#, io

I was searching the web but failed to find the correct example.

The goal is to have a function:

```
private void InsertLine(string source, string position, string content)
```

And write to a file using the StreamWriter so you do not need to read all lines because I the file is potentially huge.

My function so far:

```
    private void InsertLine(string source, string position, string content)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(source))
            throw new Exception(String.Format("Source:{0} does not exsists", source));

        var pos = GetPosition(position);
        int line_number = 0;
        string line;
        using (var fs = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var destinationReader = new StreamReader(fs);
                    var writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    while (( line = destinationReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                      if (line_number == pos)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(content);
                            break;
                        }                            
                        line_number++;
                    }
                }
    }
```

The function does not work in the file as nothing happens.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to "insert" a line without reading and writing back out the remaining lines of the file. A text file is not simply a set of linked lines, everything after that point will need to be shifted.

Comment: And you are fortunate that _nothing happens_ because your code will truncate the file to a single line. What is the code of that GetPosition? It is puzzling.

Comment: Did you debug your code and check that it actually reaches line : writer.WriteLine(content);

Comment: also wrap var writer = new StreamWriter(fs); in a using line i.e. using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fs)) {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just insert a line into a file. A file is a sequence of bytes.

You need to:

- Write all of the preceding lines
- Write the line to be inserted
- Write all of the following lines

Here's some untested code based upon yours:

```
private void InsertLine(string source, string position, string content)
{
    if (!File.Exists(source))
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Source:{0} does not exsists", source));

    // I don't know what all of this is for....
    var pos = GetPosition(position);
    int line_number = 0;
    string line;

    using (var fs = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        var destinationReader = new StreamReader(fs);
        var writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
        while (( line = destinationReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);    // ADDED: You need to write every original line

            if (line_number == pos)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(content);
                // REMOVED the break; here. You need to write all following lines
            }

            line_number++;    // MOVED this out of the if {}. Always count lines.

        }

    }
}
```

This probably won't work as expected, however. You're trying to write to the same file you're reading. You should open a new (temporary) file, perform the copy + insert, and then move/rename the temporary file to replace the original file.

Comment: I've in mind something telling me what *write all of the preceding lines* is [optional](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4573604/1997232). It may be important performance-wise when dealing with big files.

Comment: @Sinatr Excellent point. I was trying to simply modify the OP code to demonstrate what it is doing wrong. Perhaps this question would be better closed as a duplicate of the one you've linked.

Comment: I do understand what you mean but by this concept would still need to read trough the entire file. Can that be done with something like seek or that kind of technique?

Comment: Follow the link that sinatr posted above.